# Amazon Product API: ecs.amazonaws.com vs webservices.amazon.com endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Can someone explain the difference between these 2 endpoints: `ecs.amazonaws.com` and `webservices.amazon.com`  please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**webservices.amazon.com** is the Amazon.com - eShopping and Online retailer web services. Buying and Selling API

Reference http://services.amazon.com/

ecs.amazonaws.com is the Amazon Web Services' [ Cloud Computing's ] - EC2 Container Services endpoint.

Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

They both are whole lot different.

Comment: Thank you Naveen for the answer!